Celsius to Fahrenheit assembly
I am was trying to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit. Then display your Name and Fahrenheit value.
This is the output I get

and here's the code
DATA_SEG SEGMENT
    MSG_ENTER_FIRST DB 13,10,'Enter the 1st number: $'
    MSG_NAME        DB 13,10, ' '
    MSG_FAHRENHEIT  DB 13,13, 'Result of farenheit'
    FIRST_NUM       DW 0
    DIGIT_COUNT     DW 0
    CELSIUS         DB 0
    FAHRENHEIT      DB 0
DATA_SEG ENDS

CODE_SEG SEGMENT
                         ASSUME CS:CODE_SEG, DS:DATA_SEG

    START:               MOV    AX, DATA_SEG
                         MOV    DS, AX

    DISPLAY_FIRST_MSG:   
                         MOV    AH, 09
                         MOV    DX, OFFSET MSG_ENTER_FIRST
                         INT    21H

    INPUT_FIRST_NUM:     
                         MOV    AH, 01
                         INT    21H
                         CMP    AL, 13
                         SUB    AL, 48
                         MOV    BL, AL
                         MOV    BH, 0
                         MOV    FIRST_NUM, BX
                         JMP    INPUT_FIRST_NUM


    PERFORM_CALCULATIONS:
                         mov    al, [CELSIUS]
                         mov    bl, 9
                         mul    bl
                         mov    bl, 5
                         div    bl
                         add    al, 32
                         mov    [FAHRENHEIT], al
    SHOW_RESULTS:        
                         MOV    AH, 09
                         MOV    DX, OFFSET MSG_FAHRENHEIT
                         INT    21H

                         MOV    AH, 02
                         MOV    DL, ' '
                         INT    21H

                         MOV    AL, FAHRENHEIT
                         CALL   DISPLAY_NUMBER
    END_PROGRAM:         
                         MOV    AH, 4CH
                         MOV    AL, 0
                         INT    21H
DISPLAY_NUMBER PROC
                         MOV    BX, 10
    CONVERT_NUMBER:      
                         MOV    DX, 0
                         DIV    BX
                         PUSH   DX
                         INC    DIGIT_COUNT
                         CMP    AX, 0
                         JZ     OUTPUT_NUMBER
                         JMP    CONVERT_NUMBER
    OUTPUT_NUMBER:       
                         POP    DX
                         ADD    DL, 48
                         MOV    AH, 02
                         INT    21H
                         DEC    DIGIT_COUNT
                         CMP    DIGIT_COUNT, 0
                         JZ     FINISH_DISPLAY
                         JMP    OUTPUT_NUMBER
    FINISH_DISPLAY:      
                         RET
DISPLAY_NUMBER ENDP

DATA_SEG ENDS
CODE_SEG ENDS
    END START


For starters you have an infinite loop in INPUT_FIRST_NUM ... you have a CMP AL, 13 but missing the conditional jump.

Aside: it should have been easy to copy/paste the output you are getting as text. Please try to avoid screenshots.
